# How to add null to ActionLink as string linkText in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I write string linkText as null?

```
 <i class="icon-pencil" >@Html.ActionLink( null,"edit", new { id = item.content_id }) </i>
```

Comment: Because of icon image @MichalKlouda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have feeling you're using Twitter Bootstrap (because of the "icon-pencil" class on a `<i>` tag).

In that case it is better to put the `<i>` inside the `<a>` tag instead of the other way around:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("edit", new { id = item.content_id })"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

Comment: Yes I'm using twitter bootstrap :) I have tried but my string link as <i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i> not appears as icon

Answer (score -1):

replace null with :

```
string.empty
```